# Распознавание Русский и Английский одновременно на библиотеке Vosk Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, распознавание-речи, vosk

Подскажите, как подключить Speaker Identification Model чтобы одновременно распознавал русский и английский в библиотеке Vosk в Python, например: `сохранить это в папке dict-list`